# MySQL iterate information from one table in to 2 columns in query

Tags: mysql, join, iteration, left-join, conditional-aggregation

I have a database which holds maintenance reports for unique units that I need to pull information from in a single query. My issue is the convoluted way the information is stored.

```
SELECT date(reports.created_timestamp) as Date,
        locations.name as Location,
        location_groups.name as L_group,
        units.name as Unit_name,
        units.id as Unit_ID,
        concat(users_2.first_name, "           
                    ",users_2.last_name) as Engineer,
        reports.id as Report_ID 
FROM reports
LEFT JOIN units
    ON reports.unit_id = units.id
LEFT JOIN users_2
    ON reports.user_id = users_2.id
LEFT JOIN locations
    ON units.location_id = locations.id
LEFT JOIN location_groups
    ON locations.locations_group_id = location_groups.id
where reports.created_timestamp >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
and locations.name NOT LIKE 'Company Vehicles'
and location_groups.name = 'Airports';
```

This returns:

| Date | Location | L_group | Unit_name | Unit_ID | Engineer | Report_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-18 | Airport 1 | Airports | AIR-AAA1-N127 | 1 | Engineer 1 | 19471 |
| 2022-10-19 | Airport 2 | Airports | AIR-BBB2-D03 | 4 | Engineer 2 | 19486 |
| 2022-10-19 | Airport 2 | Airports | AIR-BBB2-D14 | 13 | Engineer 2 | 19495 |
| 2022-10-25 | Airport 2 | Airports | AIR-BBB2-D13 | 14 | Engineer 2 | 19518 |

However, when the engineers are completing maintenance they have to do several tasks depending on the "unit" type. This is held in the units table as unit_type_id variable. This then references display_type_report_tasks to determine what tasks should be completed based on the unit_type_id, e.g:

| id | unit_type_id | report_task_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 13 | 1 |
| 9 | 13 | 2 |
| 3 | 14 | 1 |
| 4 | 15 | 1 |

The report_task_id's then relate to table report_tasks which holds the following as an example:

| id | name | text | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Unit Cleaned-Internal | Unit Cleaned-Internal | Unit Cleaned-Internal |
| 2 | Unit Cleaned-External | Unit Cleaned-External | Unit Cleaned-External |
| 3 | Bumper Bar Fixed | Bumper Bar Fixed | Bumper Bar Fixed |
| 4 | Tile Replaced | Tile Replaced | Tile Replaced |
| 5 | Hardware Replaced | Hardware Replaced | Hardware Replaced |

Picking unit type 13 as an example, when an engineer completes a report, the task options are stored in reports_tasks_selected_options such as the following:

| id | report_tasks_option_id | example_report_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30452 | 1 | 19558 |
| 30453 | 9 | 19558 |

The report_tasks_option_id then relates to report_tasks_options:

| id | value | description | report_task_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Not cleaned | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | Internal Clean | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | Deep Clean | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | Not cleaned | 2 |
| 8 | 2 | External Clean | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | Deep Clean | 2 |

I want to query the unit_type_id and dynamically assign the column headers using report_tasks.name depending on what unit types are returned. (If a unit is returned that doesn't utilise all columns then NULL is used where no result is returned.)

I have to build reports per unit_type and statically assign the columns, BUT I cannot figure out how to then iterate through reports_tasks_selected_options to get the report_tasks_options.description for the results. As an example (using report_id = 19558) my current query output would be:

| Date | Location | L_group | Unit_name | Unit_ID | Engineer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | Airport 3 | Airports | AIR-CCC1-D09 | 1907 | Engineer 3 |

But because I know this is unit_type=13 I know that the report_tasks related to it are Unit Cleaned-Internal and Unit Cleaned-External. So I want to iterate through the reports_tasks_selected_options table for that report number (As I know that the lower ID is always Unit Cleaned-Internal because it has the lower ID in report_tasks, and so the higher ID from reports_tasks_selected_options is always going to be Unit Cleaned-External.)

Desired output:

| Date | Location | L_group | Unit_name | Unit_ID | Engineer | Report_ID | Clean-Int | Clean-Ext |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | Airport 3 | Airports | AIR-CCC1-D09 | 1907 | Engineer 3 | 19558 | Not cleaned (1) | Deep Clean (9) |

I put the option numbers in brackets for clarity but do not require them in my output.

Comment: Why are you saying iterate? It isn't necessary in relational querying. "the convoluted way the information is stored" Write queries for the tables you wish you had & use as subqueries. PS Please, smallest possible still-representative example tables. And the rest of a [mre] with parts you can do is helpful. Please, minimal mnemonic table aliases. And no DB.

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: @philipxy I need to iterate through the example_database.example_reports_tasks_selected_options because it doesn't store the task ID to which the option is associated. So the lower ID is always the first task and the higher ID is always the second task. Hope that makes sense? (I know the table structure is a bit of a mess but unfortunately I have no say in the matter)

Comment: @philipxy I have cleaned up the question now (hopefully!) and essentially what I need to do is pick the lower ID from reports_tasks_selected_options, look up the option_ID in report_tasks_options and return the description based on the ID from there and put that result in column Clean-Int. Then do the same but for the higher ID from reports_tasks_selected_options and put it in column Clean-Ext

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please act on all of my commentary. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. (I don't know why you think this is clearer. Why say "iterate" here--doing something for every value in a set isn't iteration when it is done with a relational operator. Why use left join for inner? Why not tiny table aliases?) PS A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. [ask] [Help]